# How to display all taxonomy terms as tree view in block drupal 6?

Tags: drupal-6, drupal-taxonomy

I want to display all taxonomy terms as tree view in block.

A
-A1
-A2
-A3
B
-B1
-B2

How do I display like this. Please reply

Answer (score 0):

The taxonomy_get_tree() function should get you the raw data you need.